# Difficulty with Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I'm trying to make a Telerik Kendo grid of audit records, with a sub grid presenting the details of each main record.

I'm getting a syntax error which I don't understand.

```
@model IEnumerable<AuditRecord>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("AuditGrid")
    .DetailTemplate(auditrec =>
    {
        @<text>
        @(Html.Telerik()
             .Grid(auditrec.Details)
             .Name("Detail_" + auditrec.ID.ToString()))
        </text>
    }))
```

Error message follows, with the line `@<text>` flagged as the source of the error:

> CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new
>   object expressions can be used as a statement

This is modeled after the Telerik example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/hierarchyserverside).

What am I getting wrong about the Razor syntax? The <% syntax isn't working for me, either.

Comment: try `<text>` without the Razor `@`

Comment: That moves the error to the next line: `CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @`.  If I remove the @ on that line, the error moves back up one line and reads: `CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'`

Comment: I dont think you need the `@` identifier inside the block. try removing it.

Comment: It just moves the error back up one line and says the < is invalid.  This is so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting like this is tricky, but try this syntax

```
@{Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("AuditGrid")
    .DetailTemplate(auditrec =>
    {
        @<text>
        @{@Html.Telerik()
             .Grid(auditrec.Details)
             .Name("Detail_" + auditrec.ID.ToString())
        }
        </text>
    })
}
```